# Dropdown Selected Value not Saving in DB

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am new to Codeigniter and created a project in which dropdown grab the data from table 1 and I want to save the data to table 2.  However, the other value option is saving but not dropdown values.  Code is given below.

Model:

```
function getPriviousScore() {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('ielts_previous_score');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Controller:

```
$data['ielts_previous_score'] = $this->enquiry_model->getPriviousScore();
```

View:

```
<select name="ielts_previous_score" class="form-control">
    <option value=""><?php echo $this->lang->line('select'); ?></option>  
    <?php foreach ($ielts_previous_score as $key => $value) { ?>
        <option value="<?php print_r($value['ielts_previous_score']); ?>" <?php if (set_value('ielts_previous_score') == $value['ielts_previous_score']) { ?>selected=""<?php } ?>><?php print_r($value['ielts_previous_score']); ?></option>
    <?php } ?>                                       
</select>
```

Comment: Welcome to Codeigniter. Your query and code look ok (although the getPrevious function could be simplified to just $this->db->get('table_name')->result_array() and there is a form_dropdown helper available that will make / handle the select box for you). When you do print_r($_POST) on your receiving page - what data do you get? We cannot see from your question where/how you are trying to save the data to your database so if you can provide a bit more info then we'll be able to advise :o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MODEL

```
  function getPriviousScore() {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('ielts_previous_score');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
  }
```

CONTROLLER

```
   $data['ielts_previous_score'] = $this->enquiry_model->getPriviousScore();
```

VIEW

```
 <select name="ielts_previous_score" class="form-control">
 <option value=""><?php echo $this->lang->line('select'); ?></option>  
 <?php foreach ($ielts_previous_score as $key => $value) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $value['ielts_previous_score']; ?>" <?php if 
    (set_value('ielts_previous_score') == $value['ielts_previous_score']) { ? 
  >selected=""<?php } ?>><?php echo $value['ielts_previous_score']; ?></option>
 <?php } ?>
 </select>
```